# Launching a Fragment from an Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to launch a fragment from my main activity, but whenever i try to launch the fragment it just overlays what is on the fragment over the main activity.
Here is the mainActivity.java

```
if(passwordEntered.equals(true)&& userNameEntered.equals(true))
                {
                    if(passwordString.equals("theadmin")&&usernameString.equals("admin"))
                    {
                        Intent adminIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,EmptyActivity.class);
                        startActivity(adminIntent);
                    }
                }
```

And here is adminpage.java, but it's supposed to run the homefragment, which it does, but it overalys the mainActivity

```
public static FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    public static MyAppDatabase myAppDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        myAppDatabase= Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),MyAppDatabase.class,"userSdb").allowMainThreadQueries().build();

        if(findViewById(R.id.fragmentContainer)!=null)
        {
            if(savedInstanceState!=null)
            {
                return;
            }
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer,new HomeFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen???

Comment: Also add your layout XML. If you are using frame layout, i suppose what you are getting is the expected behaviour.

Comment: @m__ I expected to just see a fragment with the mainActivity not in the background

Comment: So you mean your other layouts are in front and your fragment goes in background. Please share your activity's layout file. Where you add container for your fragment.

Comment: `FragmentTransaction`s only handle `Fragment`s' `View`s. They won't remove/replace any other `View`s. If you want to replace the `Activity`'s `View`s with a `Fragment`, put those `View`s into their own `Fragment` that you can `replace()` with your other `Fragment`s.